# Вывод строки, меньшей в лексикографическом порядке

Tags: java, строки

Программа получает на вход две строки. Необходимо вывести строку, меньшую в лексографическом порядке

В лексографическом порядке - это значит по алфавиту.

```
Пример: Ввод - look picture.
        Вывод - look.

Или Ввод - крошка картошка.
    Вывод - картошка.
```

Мой код работает нормально, пока сравниваемые слова начинаются с разных букв, когда же слова с одной и той же буквы начинаются - все валится, т.к. он не сравнивает вторые буквы в словах. Подскажите, как мне это исправить?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc.next();
    String s2 = sc.next();
    if(s1.charAt(0) > s2.charAt(0)){
        System.out.print(s2);
    }
    else{
        System.out.print(s1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать все намного проще - использовать метод [compareTo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1137), который как раз сравнивает строки в легсиграфическом порядке. Ваше код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = sc.next();
    String s2 = sc.next();
    int diff = s1.compareTo(s2);
    if (diff < 0) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    } else if (diff > 0) {
        System.out.println(s2);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Строки равны");
    }
}
```